# Zoom In And Zoom Out In Clash Of Clans Running On Android X86

Tags: android-x86, zooming, clash-of-clans

Hey guys am running Android x86 9.0 r2 on my pc and its running great, i am playing clash of clans on it and it works great but i can't zoom out as we do on phone as pinch like with two fingers, I don't have touch screen am looking for a way to do this as bases are wide its hard to move through mouse so looking for zoom as second of time waste to move in base with mouse ruin my raids following are things i tried :-

1. I tried a app called assertive touch still no success.
2. I tried all shortcut keys found on Google search like double click then hold and move up mouse or move down.

but none of work if anyone knows something let me know and be safe.

Comment: Have you read this topic and the answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023554/not-able-to-pinch-zoom-on-emulator

Comment: Ya i have tried that mentioned in second point that keys referred in your attached thread

Comment: That shortcut keys only work to zoom in and out on pictures not in application like game